# What exactly is stored in the buffer array in the code below? Is it the values of x[n-k] or something else?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, impulse-response

What exactly is stored in the buffer array in the FIR Filter code below? Is it the values of x[n-k] or something else?

```
float filter (float value){
    for (int i = ntaps-1; i>0; i--){
        buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];
    }
    buffer[0] = value;
    for (int i = 0; i<ntaps; i++){
        output += buffer[i]*h[i];
    }
    return ouput;
}
```

Comment: please edit and correct the missing code and put relevant information on the variables and the buffer data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores the last $ntap$ samples of the input. So it's $x[n], x[n-1], ..., x[n-N+1]$

Comment: But x[n], x[n-1],... x[n-N+1] are delayed versions of the signal x[n] whereas the buffer array stores numerical values, not signals. What exactly are the numerical values in the buffer array?